# Trying to hide elements depending on route angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im trying to make a dynamic nav where when you are on the regular website it shows a full nav but if you are on certain paths e.g `http://mywebsite.com/path` I want it to hide certain nav items and show another nav item

my setup for this is..

**app.component.html**

```
<ul (click)="navLinkClick()" class="nav-page_ul">
    <a *ngIf="!routeHidden" [routerLink]="['']"><li class="go-to-website">go to site</li></a>
    <a *ngIf="routeHidden" [routerLink]="['1']"><li>1</li></a>
    <a *ngIf="routeHidden" [routerLink]="['2']"><li>2</li></a>
    <a *ngIf="routeHidden" [routerLink]="['3']"><li>3</li></a>
    <a *ngIf="routeHidden" [routerLink]="['4']"><li>4</li></a>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.router.events.subscribe( (e) => {
  if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
    if (e.url === '/6' || e.url === '/7' || e.url === '/8' || '/9') {
      this.routeHidden = false;
    } else {
      this.routeHidden = true;
    }
  }
});
}
```

now what happens is no matter what route Im on it only shows the `go-to-website` nav item and none of the rest

Im not sure what Im doing wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: `e.url === '/8' || '/9'` may be an issue, change it to `e.url === '/8' || e.url === 
 '/9'`

Comment: @AswinRamesh you sir are a genius! thank you this fixed my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your condition, `e.url === '/8' || '/9'` may be an issue

change it to `e.url === '/8' || e.url === '/9'`